# What fastener to use to attach 4" circular pan to steel stud?

Tags: studs, steel, junction-box, fastener

I need to attach a 4" circular pan circuit box to a steel stud in order to hang a bathroom vanity light fixture. The fixture weights less than 10 lbs, but assume some future homeowner will want to install a bigger fixture -- but maximum of 20 lbs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the steel stud is of sufficient thickness/strength you could fasten it with self-drilling [Tek screws](http://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fcdn.greenhousemegastore.com%2Fimages%2Fproducts%2Fscrew-1000-dd.jpg&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.greenhousemegastore.com%2Fproduct%2Ftek-screws-10-16-x-3_4%2Fscrews-and-hardware&h=243&w=250&tbnid=nQ919AAbuxRS9M%3A&zoom=1&docid=eAhlSV33l9PWZM&ei=Z8HnU-vqFY7yoAS45oKQBg&tbm=isch&ved=0CDQQMygBMAE&iact=rc&uact=3&dur=1831&page=1&start=0&ndsp=23). I would personally be more concerned with the weight bearing capability of the steel stud (assuming it is the lightweight steel studs commonly used in commercial build-outs in my area).

Most ceiling fixtures (you use the term stud rather than joist so I am assuming wall mount) that are expected to hold any weight should be attached to a [cross-brace](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&docid=CKVobyvIUv0Y_M&tbnid=DAKUdeleY44TpM:&ved=0CAUQjRw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2FWestinghouse-Lighting-0152500-Saf-T-Bar-Engineered%2Fdp%2FB0002YV94A&ei=P8LnU5ywM6HXiwL664GICw&bvm=bv.72676100,d.cGU&psig=AFQjCNENv6IsNCh8o_sjnOUm7ptaY78BaQ&ust=1407783553147596) which is attached to two joists.

Consider using a long pilot drill and drill through both the front and back sides of the steel stud, then use a long self-tapping screw to penetrate both sides of the stud.